# FILTER formula rows and columns, excel

Tags: excel, filter, row, formula, multiple-columns

I have a data set, where I need to FILTER data according to columns and rows.

In excel support the suggestion is to use filtered data as array. I have done it (using fiter for columns, but I keep getting #value! error.

My current formula looks like this:
=FILTER(FILTER('[MBS Sourcing Instructions V17.9 (1).xlsx]Buying Channel_Exception'!$A$1:$NI$194,'[MBS Sourcing Instructions V17.9 (1).xlsx]Buying Channel_Exception'!$A$1:$NI$2=C4),'[MBS Sourcing Instructions V17.9 (1).xlsx]Buying Channel_Exception'!$D$1:$D$194=C2,""),

Now I need to filter the data according to the row A - country (starting from column F and then it consist of 4 next columns for each country) and to columns D (commodity code)

Kindly find sample data below.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfEa8.png)

Comment: Post sample data as text.

Comment: I am new to this forum, is there a way of posting data in format of table or should I post it as sheer text (in that case it looks messy).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the fact that you are referencing a range of 2 rows in

`Buying Channel_Exception'!$A$1:$NI$2`

I presume this is because you have merged cells for your header and sub-header rows?

In any case, this needs to be a reference to a single row, for example

`Buying Channel_Exception'!$A$1:$NI$1`

Comment: Hello Jos,
Thank you so much for your answer, to be 100% honest I have done it before, but probably something was wrong with the formula elsewhere as it is still had given me #value! error.
This time I rewrote the formula, taking into consideration your advice and it worked!
Thank you so much!